# weird action on AJAX form submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

stuck half a day on a part of my code on `localhost`, part of submit form with uploading file, i simulated my codes in `jsfiddle` to show you how it works:

```
var params = $('#add-form').serializeArray();

  $.each(params, function(i, val) {
    form.append(val.name, val.value);
  });

  if (files != null) {
    $.each(files, function(key, value) {
      form.append(key, value);
    });
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kf2zyq45/2/)</kbd>

**Problem:**

If user chooses a file it works fine and submit successfully but if does not select a file it won't submit to `db`, I'm pretty sure there are no conditions in my `PHP` code to prevent submitting without file and also pretty sure no problem with my `PHP` it worked with `serialize` and that and at that time there was no file uploading, after i switch to `DataForm` this problem occurred.

This part of PHP get `file` and process it:

```
$safename = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["name"]);

if($_FILES){
uploadVid($nameVid, $adsid, $userid);
}
```

If need more information/code to solve this problem please tell me to update the question.

*Thanks in advance*

**Edit:** Network result:

```
Request URL:http://example.com/index.php?post
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:x.x.x.x:xxx
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Comment: You are checking for `if ($_FILES)` - otherwise, `uploadVid()` is not called. Is the database insert handled inside that function? Also, you didn't show us you markup... Might there be a required attribute set to the file input? We can only guess whether the problem is on the client side or on the server side without more information.

Comment: No Inserting to `db` not in this function `uploadVid()` it just have `move_uploaded_file` and etc. This part of `php code` is huge! i don't know can i copy/paste here? or which part of code should be copy here. @Connum

Comment: Can you take a look into the network tab of your browser's developer console and see whether the post request is being sent at all? That would help to understand if it's a client-side or server-side problem.

Comment: But as i said, before i use `FormData` and add `uploading input` it worked fine but after that this problem occurred. due to this i say pretty sure there are no problem in php. EDIT: yes, I will.

Comment: @Connum it called `index.php?post`, i updated question with result. also preview and response are empty. Update: And also nothing in `errorlog`